# How to control number of threads by using pthread_join in C?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, pthread-join

I have created a C program which will read 20000 strings from a text file, and send it to other program. I have used a while to loop through this text file and create threads which will send that text to the other program. 
But I want only 4 threads to work. so I have used a counter and keep decrementing it, and an if condition to check the counter and when it will be set to 1 then I have called pthread_join for the previous threads. 
I want to first finish these 4 threads and then new 4 threads to pick up the new text file strings.
But it is not working as I need. it processes only every 4th thread 4 times. and doesnt picks up all records from the text file.

Program:-

```
int Read_record()
{
    printf("Inside Read_record()\n");
    pthread_t threads;
    int rc;
    char l_record[300];
    int thNum=4;

    while(1){
        MEMSET(g_record);

        if(fgets(g_record,300,g_r_fp)==NULL){
            printf("End of File.\n");
            break;
        }else{
            //printf("%s",g_record);
            printf("%s",g_record);
            rc = pthread_create(&threads, NULL, &Get_report, (void *)g_record);

            if (rc){
                printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
                exit(-1);
            }

            thNum--;
        }

        if(thNum==0){ 
            pthread_join(threads, NULL); 
            thNum=4;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Input Text file contains: 1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14

Out put comes:-

```
Inside Read_record()
1
2
3
4
Inside Get_report, wget 4

Inside Get_report, wget 4

Inside Get_report, wget 4

Inside Get_report, wget 4

5
6
7
8
Inside Get_report, wget 8

Inside Get_report, wget 8

Inside Get_report, wget 8

Inside Get_report, wget 8

9
10
11
12
Inside Get_report, wget 12

Inside Get_report, wget 12

Inside Get_report, wget 12

Inside Get_report, wget 12

13
14
15
16
Inside Get_report, wget 16

Inside Get_report, wget 16

Inside Get_report, wget 16

Inside Get_report, wget 16

17
18
19
20
Inside Get_report, wget 20

Inside Get_report, wget 20

Inside Get_report, wget 20

Inside Get_report, wget 20

End of File.
```

Desire Output:-

```
Inside Get_report, wget 1
Inside Get_report, wget 2
Inside Get_report, wget 3
Inside Get_report, wget 4

Inside Get_report, wget 5
Inside Get_report, wget 6
Inside Get_report, wget 7
Inside Get_report, wget 8

Inside Get_report, wget 9
Inside Get_report, wget 10
Inside Get_report, wget 11
Inside Get_report, wget 12.
and so on..
```

Please mind I want only 4 threads to create in system. not more than that.

Comment: You create four threads, but save the thread id to only one variable (overwriting each time you create a thread), so you will only join the last thread.

Comment: Thanks Joachim. Do you want me to create 4 different thread variables, and then put a join for each thread ? like thread1. thread2. thread3, thread4. and then pthread_join(thread1,NULL), pthread_join(thread2,NULL), pthread_join(thread3,NULL), pthread_join(thread4,NULL) ? but would it be Multithreading ?

Comment: An array would probably be better, as you can then use e.g. `thNum` to index it on creation.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like what you need is a thread pool, whereby you create a pool of 4 threads and communicate the work to them via a queue. The main thread will read the file and enqueue jobs (object/struct with the line of text to process) on the queue. The threads will take a job off the queue, process the job, and then get another job.

The threads should not exit after processing just one job, but just loop until told to stop.

Answer (score 1):

There is something fundamentally wrong with the structure of your program.  Here is what i think you want:

1. Have the main method read the strings
2. Have the main method create 4 threads (store them in an array or something)
3. Implement some form of shared memory to send the data to the 4 threads
4. You will probably need some form of synchronization.
5. after the work is done terminate and join on all 4 threads

hope this gets you on your way to the wonderful world of threading

This is in fact a [thread pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern) as mentioned in the other post

And i found [this wonderful tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) on threads, i only looked through the index table but seems to have everything you need covered.

Comment: however you want to call it :) The word is just borrowed from languages where this object is implemented in the standard libs

Comment: Your answer is completely correct, but the point was that it sounds very similar (possibly too similar) to the answer already posted.

Comment: Could be, although imho my answer is a little bit better to get a starting programmer started. And i'll add a link to the thread pool pattern, it's actually completely the same ^^

Comment: I think there is a need to mention mutex (or any other synchronization) mechanism regarding the shared memory queue.

Comment: That depends on the implementation. If all data transactions are initialized by the main thread and different pieces of shared memory are used there is no need for a locking mechanism. Although I see your point and will update my post in a minute.

Comment: Synchronization is absolutely necessary for a shared resource, either implicitly or explicitly, depending on the implementation used.

Comment: That is correct, but you don't need any locking mechanism for implicit synchronization, which is what i said

Comment: When I mention implicit, I mean its implemented internally in the queue.